# MySQL table with two parents - during row deletion, the delete doesn't cascade - Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I have a pretty simple SQL schema that is having trouble with cascading deletes.

Basically I want to have:

- `Users` table w/ an Email
- `Items` table w/

  - `text`
  - `createdByUser` foreign key (parent #1)
  - optional `parent` item foreign key (parent #2)

Items have two parents - a user, and optionally another item (so they can be hierarchical).

My problem comes with the cascading deleting of the `Items` when I delete a `User`. If I delete the user that created items, then I expect all of those items to be deleted. However, items that have a `parentItem` as well are NOT deleted, and instead the `parentItem` was just set to `NULL`.

On MySQL 5.6, (on sqlfiddle.com) this seems to work fine. But on MySQL 5.7 (on Google Cloud), this has the problem that the `"DA"` item is not deleted below.

Here is the schema & insertion commands:

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Items;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

CREATE TABLE Users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE Items (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  parentItem INT DEFAULT NULL,
  text TEXT NOT NULL,
  createdByUser INT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (createdByUser),
  INDEX (parentItem),

  FOREIGN KEY (createdByUser)
    REFERENCES Users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (parentItem)
    REFERENCES Items (id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO Users (email) VALUES
  ("test@email.com")
  ;

SET @temp_user_id = (select id from Users where email="test@email.com" LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO Items (text, createdByUser) VALUES
  ("A", @temp_user_id),
  ("B", @temp_user_id),
  ("C", @temp_user_id),
  ("D", @temp_user_id)
  ;

SET @temp_item_id = (select id from Items where text = "D" LIMIT 1);

INSERT INTO Items (parentItem, text, createdByUser) VALUES
  (@temp_item_id, "DA", @temp_user_id)
  ;

DELETE From Users where id = @temp_user_id;

SELECT * FROM Users;
SELECT * From Items;
```

I expect the output to be empty for both tables. But in MySQL 5.7 on Google Cloud, Items still has 1 row, `"DA"`:

```sql
+----+------------+------+---------------+
| id | parentItem | text | createdByUser |
+----+------------+------+---------------+
|  5 |       NULL | DA   |             1 |
+----+------------+------+---------------+
```

What am I doing wrong here?

For reference, here is what Google's MySQL is telling me about the tables:

```sql
| Users | CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

```sql
| Items | CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentItem` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `createdByUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `createdByUser` (`createdByUser`),
  KEY `parentItem` (`parentItem`),
  CONSTRAINT `Items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`createdByUser`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`parentItem`) REFERENCES `Items` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

Comment: Hm. It works just fine on my MySQL 5.7.23 and MariaDB 10.1.14. I mean table Items is empty after deleting the user.

Comment: That's frustrating - I don't know the sub-version for Google's database - maybe they have known issue quirks here? I guess I'm also not doing a great job w/ the way I'm storing hierarchical data here, maybe I should ditch the parentItem and do a closure table?

Comment: Google Cloud has 2 versions of Cloud MySQL 5.7.14 and MySQL 5.6.42. I checked on 5.6 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the old 5.7.14 from official MySQL site to reproduce your scenario and received same result. I tried with 5.6.42 and 5.7.26 (the latest one) and the table is empty. Seems like this is MySQL internal bug. In your situation you can use Google Cloud MySQL 5.6 version.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this! Crazy that I found a MySQL bug - I guess I just shouldn't use key constraints and just use transactions instead :/